# Creating a File to array function

Tags: c

Currently I have the argc, argv and temp pieces placed in to be passed, and when I compile it returns no errors, but when I call the function later in the program and pass it a char array. It returns a stack dump. From what I have learned so far arrays cannot be passed back from a function and that is why I have passed the pointers.

```
int In2File(int argc, char *argv[], char *temp[] ){

    if (argc == 2) { //open file
        FILE *user_file;
        user_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (user_file == NULL) {
            printf("No data was found.\nEnd(Error 1)");
            exit(2);
        }
        else {
            int g = 0;//temp counter to load
            char c = 0;
            while ((c = fgetc(user_file)) != EOF && g <= tmplng - 1) { //Used Fgetc instead of fgets because Fgetc allows me to read
                *temp[g] = c;                      //until the end of the file and read each character. Even if there is an \n character.
                g++;                              // The second g < tmplng-1 is used to make sure that the \0 can be placed into the array.
            }
            printf("%s\n", temp);
            fclose(user_file);//Closed the txt file that was loaded by user in args(1)          
            printf("\nFile Loaded.\n");
        }
    }
    else if (argc > 2) { // Will exit if arguments are greater than 2.
        printf("Format: %s 'filename'", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("File not provided. Enter information:\n");//If the user doesnt provide a file allow manual input.
        fgets(*temp, tmplng, stdin);
    }
}
```

In2File(argc,argv,temp);

Anyone have an idea as to where I went wrong with this function? I read a few similar posts but they were for C++ and Python. Which I havent learned C++ as yet and python is different to this beast called C.

Edit:

```
const int tmplng = 1000; //The only variables needed
    char temp[tmplng];       //
    char temp2[tmplng];      //

    printf("Starting....\n"); //Used for testing debugging.
```

Comment: The code would be easier to follow if you remove all the unnecessary `else` statements which clutter it. For example after `exit(2);` there is no possible `else`.

Comment: Add more of your code as some things can't be understood clearly, like what is tmplng?

Comment: How is this function called, and how is the third argument declared?

Comment: There is an "if" a little further above used to check if the file returned NULL, if it does then it will exit. @WeatherVane Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho My apologies, I have added it

Comment: Please add main() part too as you were saying "when I call the function later in the program and pass it a char array.". Later when?

Comment: Note that `const int tmplng = 1000;` means that `char temp[tmplng];` is a VLA (variable length array).  C++ has different rules, but in C, it's a VLA.  It doesn't hurt anything — you should just be aware.

Comment: I just added what you were looking for, I apologize, didnt know it would be needed. @dbush

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho was just added.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because it is a VLA am I unable to pass it to the function? If so what do you believe would be a good fix?

Comment: No; there's no problem passing a VLA to a function.  You can't initialize a VLA (so `char temp[tmplng] = "";` shouldn't compile), but that's about the only problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. That could cause problems because I am not initializing it right? Ok bud I see where you are getting at, thank you I will look for another way.

Comment: You don't ensure that the string in `temp` is null-terminated; that's an important problem.  You do set `temp[0]` when `g = 0`, so you're initializing from the start.  What I pointed out is a minor detail.  You could avoid the VLA by using `enum { tmplng = 1000 };` instead of `const int tmplng = 1000;`, or using `#define tmplng 1000` (but the enum is better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter to the function doesn't match what the function is expecting.  You're passing in a `char []` (which decays to a `char *`), while the function expects `char *[]` (equivalently `char **` as a function parameter).

The definition of the third parameter doesn't match how you intend to use it, which is as a character array.

Get rid of the extra level of indirection on the parameter, and adjust the function accordingly.

```
int In2File(int argc, char *argv[], char temp[] ){
        ...
        while ((c = fgetc(user_file)) != EOF && g <= tmplng - 1) { 
            temp[g] = c; 
            g++;  
        }
```

Comment: Ok bud, I will do it now. Thanks you very much for your time and assistance. So just to clarify, when I pass a pointer of a pointer I use the double asterisk(**)?

Comment: @DamaniAPhilip Correct.  In this case you just have a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration of `temp`:

> ```
> char temp[tmplng];
> ```

... does not go with this call ...

> ```
> In2File(argc,argv,temp);
> ```

... to this function ...

> ```
> int In2File(int argc, char *argv[], char *temp[] );
> ```

The function expects its third argument to be a pointer to a pointer to `char *`, but what it receives is a pointer to `char`.  When it then tries to assign the character read ...

> ```
>     *temp[g] = c;
> ```

That attempts to interpret the `g`<sup>th</sup> element of `temp` (itself interpreted as a `char **`) as a `char *`, to *dereference* that pointer, and to assign `c` to that location.  That is highly unlikely to be a valid memory access.

It looks like you want to declare the third argument of `In2File` as either `char *temp` or `char temp[]`, which are equivalent, and to write to it as `temp[g] = c`.

ALSO, as an aside, note that your

> ```
> printf("%s\n", temp);
> ```

is problematic because you do not ensure that `temp` is null-terminated.  And inasmuch as you support reading up to the very last byte, you don't have room to terminate it.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation, I also marked yours with the check, and I understand it now this helped me a lot. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

As numerous folks are pointing out in the comments, your code would be much easier to understand if you employed "early exit" for your error conditions.

It would also be a better separation of concerns to have `main` deal with the program arguments and let `In2File` just deal with a file pointer.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    FILE *fp;

    if( argc == 2 ) {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if ( fp == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    else if( argc > 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <optional filename>", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        fp = stdin;
    }

    char *lines = In2File(fp);

    printf("%s\n", lines);

    free(lines);
}
```

Note that `stdin` is a file pointer just like anything you opened with `fopen`. I've also used `strerror` and `errno` to provide the reason the file didn't open.

Now `In2File` just takes a file pointer. Also note that I have it returning the content, not passing in a preallocated array. This is because when reading from input you never know how much input you're going to get. You either must stop reading before you run out of space, or allocate more memory. You can't reallocate stack memory, so it's best to let `In2File` control allocating memory. It also avoids having to pass around a global variable.

Once that's done, `In2File` becomes much simpler.

```
static char *In2File( FILE *fp ){
    size_t read_size = 1024;

    /* Don't forget space for null */
    char *content = calloc( read_size + 1, sizeof(char) );

    fread( content, sizeof(char), read_size, fp );

    return content;
}
```

Rather than step through a character at a time, I've used `fread` to read a block from the file not larger than the amount I've allocated. Memory reallocation is a topic for another time.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am going to research those new functions that you put in like stderr, errno, and calloc. I have not learned these as yet, and it looks like I got in over my head at the moment in trying to make this function. lol I have a lot more reading to do, back to the book(s).